# QML ButtonRow checkedButton not responding

Tags: qt, button, row, qml, qt-quick

When I call this:

```
buttonrow1.checkedButton = _button1
```

then I get no errors and nothing happens, I can also not change the property using states, no matter what I do it just remains at the default setting. Any idea how I can change this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

buttonrow is not a built in type. So please add your definition and tell us what you need to do with:

```
buttonrow1.checkedButton = _button1
```